# Should navigation property be nullable or not

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Look at this entity:

```
class EntityA
{
   public int Id { get;set; }
   public string Name { get;set; }
   public int? ClientId { get; set; }

   // Navigation properties:
   public ClientEntity? Client { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, this entity contains an optional property: ClientId. This means the client is optional. In this case, the ClientId field will contain NULL in the sql server database.

I am working with navigation properties for foreign keys: This is the "Client" property. When ClientId is null, Client should be null too.

This is why i have declared: "ClientEntity?" type for the Client property.

But i see people who declare "ClientEntity" (not nullable) in same circumstances.
But i do not understand how they can manipulate null clients in this case...

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Imagine project with not enabled "nullable reference types" -  this is what you saw. If it works for you - go on.

Comment: I want to understand: I have tried to disable "nullable reference types" and it works without error: I can put null in a non nullable object. How can this be possible ? Thanks

Comment: Not a super expert in EF Core and its conventions. But probably because FK  `ClientId` is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this for anyone that also ran into this when enabling nullability for their project, the Navigational Properties should not be Nullable.

Per Microsoft,

> Collection navigations, which contain references to multiple related entities, should always be non-nullable. An empty collection means that no related entities exist, but the list itself should never be null.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types

So the solution to code this would be:

```
class EntityA
{
   public int Id { get;set; }
   public string Name { get;set; }
   public int ClientId { get; set; }

   // Navigation properties:
   public ClientEntity Client { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: The link you quote from Microsoft is talking about collection navigations, i.e. ICollection   Yet your example is a 1-1 reference to a single entity

Comment: I find the lesser evil is to declare them as shown in this answer, but the given reason is too simplistic. Navigation properties can be null just because they're not included in the query. So we would ideally want them to be nullable until they're included using Include, and then be non-nullable. But C# can't do that. So you have to choose between several bad options.